# React - Resetting children state when parent changes its state in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance, state

I'm working with a list of notes in React Native, and I was using a bad-performant method to select/deselect the notes when I'm "edit mode". Everytime I selected a note, the application had to re-render the entire list everytime. If I do a test with 100 notes, I get input lags when I select/deselect a note, obviously.

So I decided to move the "select state" to the single Child component. By doing this, I'm having the re-render only on that component, so it's a huge improvement of performance. Until here, everything's normal.

The problem is when I'm disabling edit mode. If I select, for example, 3 notes, and I disable the "edit mode", those notes will remain selected (indeed also the style will persist). I'd like to reset the state of all the selected note, or finding a valid alternative.

I recreated the scene using React (not React Native) on CodeSandbox with a Parent and a Child: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-field-bh0k9k

The behavior is exactly the same. I hope you can help me out. Thanks.

**tl;dr**:

*Use-case*:

1. Go in Edit Mode by selecting a note for .5s
2. Select 2/3 elements by clicking on them
3. Disable Edit Mode by selecting a note for .5s

*Expectation*: all elements get deselected (state of children resetted)

*Reality*: elements don't get deselected (state of children remains the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is easy enough to do with a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.
It allows you to "watch" variable changes over time.

When `editMode` changes the contents of the Effect hook runs, so when `editMode` goes from `true` to `false`, it will set the item's `selected` state.

Add this to your `<Child />` component:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editMode) {
      setSelected(false);
    }
  }, [editMode]);
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel so stupid... This is what happens when you overthink... Thanks for the (obvious) solution mate.

Comment: No problem, `useEffect` is a nifty one!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) you can cache the Child components and prevent their re-renders.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [childrenList, setChildrenList] = useState(INITIAL_LIST);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const toggleEditMode = useCallback(() => {
    if (editMode) {
      setSelected([]);
    }
    setEditMode(!editMode);
  }, [editMode]);

  const deleteSelectedChildren = () => {
    setChildrenList(childrenList.filter((x) => !selected.includes(x.id)));
    setEditMode(false);
  };

  const onSelect = useCallback((id) => {
    setSelected((prev) => {
      if (prev.includes(id)) {
        return prev.filter((x) => x !== id);
      }
      return [...prev, id];
    });
  }, []);

  // Check when <Parent /> is re-rendered
  console.log("Parent");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Long press an element to enable "Edit Mode"</h1>
      <ul className="childrenWrapper">
        {childrenList.map((content, index) => (
          <Child
            key={content.id}
            index={index}
            content={content}
            editMode={editMode}
            toggleEditMode={toggleEditMode}
            onSelect={onSelect}
            selected={selected.includes(content.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {editMode && (
        <button onClick={deleteSelectedChildren}>DELETE SELECTED</button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

You have to wrap the functions you pass as props inside `useCallback`, otherwise they will be different on every Parent render, invalidating the memoization.

```js
import { useRef, memo } from "react";

const Child = memo(
  ({ content, editMode, toggleEditMode, onSelect, selected }) => {
    // Prevent re-rendering when setting timer thread
    const timerRef = useRef();

    // Toggle selection of the <Child /> and update selectedChildrenIndexes
    const toggleCheckbox = () => {
      if (!editMode) return;
      onSelect(content.id);
    };

    // Toggle Edit mode after .5s of holding press on a Child component
    const longPressStartHandler = () => {
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(toggleEditMode, 500);
    };

    // Release setTimeout thread in case it's pressed less than .5s
    const longPressReleaseHandler = () => {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    };

    // Check when <Child /> is re-rendered
    console.log("Child - " + content.id);

    return (
      <li
        className={`childContent ${editMode && "editMode"} ${
          selected && "selected"
        }`}
        onMouseDown={longPressStartHandler}
        onMouseUp={longPressReleaseHandler}
        onClick={toggleCheckbox}
      >
        <pre>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(content)}</code>
        </pre>
        {editMode && (
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleCheckbox} checked={selected} />
        )}
      </li>
    );
  }
);
```

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-flower-x3xitg?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read it better after lunch, but at the moment I gave to Harrison the accepted answer because it was so basic and obvious. Thumbs up anyway, thanks.

Comment: P.s.: I decided to use an object to store the indexes of selected children because it's less expensive in terms of temporal complexity (O-big). Image selecting 50, 51, 52, ... elements and doing this everytime: return prev.filter((x) => x !== id);  

Anyway, I need to deepen my knowledge on useMemo, memo and useCallback, because I never used them in real projects, and they can obviously save performance.

Comment: Yeah that was just for the example, I would use `Set` in the final environment. Anyhow if a user needs to select 50 items, I think you'll rather have a UX problem ^^

Comment: Yes sure, it's an unreal case. Thanks anyway